# Redmine Documentor

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Have anyone used Redmine Documentor which lets you convert PHP to HTML to Redmine wiki format? If so do anyone have some recommendations or alternatives? I seems pretty cool to me.

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/3096/documentor-php-html-redmine-class-documentation-tool/p1

http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/documentor/wiki/

***Actual Documentor Link:***

http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/php/redmine/documentor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good to some extent. But it messes up some things and also ignore some annotations like @returns, @link.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a cool idea, but I just tried it and found that it mixed comments up and made a mess of things.  For example, I tried the sample code here:

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_sample2.pkg.html